# Crear url a partir de un array en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
$scope.arreglo = [
        {"clave_acceso":"122"},
      {"clave_acceso":"222"},
      {"clave_acceso":"333"}
    ];
```

y a partir de el deseo crear una url la cual debería ser como la siguiente:
Si el arreglo posee un dato: http:services/autorizaciones?ca=122
Si el arreglo posee mas de un dato: http:services/autorizaciones?ca=122&ca=222&ca=33.......etc

en mi controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
$scope.url ="";
    $scope.arreglo = [
        {"clave_acceso":"122"},
      {"clave_acceso":"222"},
      {"clave_acceso":"333"}
    ];

        for(var i =0; i < $scope.arreglo.length;i++){
        if($scope.arreglo.length >= 2){
        $scope.url="http:services/autorizaciones?ca="+$scope.arreglo[i].clave_acceso+"&ca="+$scope.arreglo[i].clave_acceso;
        }else{
            $scope.url="http:services/autorizaciones?ca="+$scope.arreglo[i].clave_acceso;
        }
      }
```

y al final de todo imprimo en mi vista html la url

```
<h5>{{url}}</h5>
```

Pero algo estoy haciendo mal que no se presenta como espero.

Como puedo solucionarlo? de antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente concatenaremos las `clave_acceso` a un string `url = "http:services/autorizaciones";`

```js
var arreglo = [{
  "clave_acceso": "122"
}, {
  "clave_acceso": "222"
}, {
  "clave_acceso": "333"
}];
url = "http:services/autorizaciones";
for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
  url += "&ca=" + arreglo[i].clave_acceso;
}
url = url.replace("&", "?");
console.log(url)
```

**cuando termina el for el resultado es** :

`http:services/autorizaciones&ca=122&ca=222&ca=333`

y con la función replace eliminamos el primer `&` y lo remplazamos con `?`

la variable `url` usala para mostrar en la vista

Comment: Muchas Gracias Excelente Respuesta...!!